# Jquery help for current time indication within a range

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a simple light-weight jquery plugin that'll help me show something like this in my website:

[image]

Essentially, this is like a timeline. I know the start and end dates (in that, they don't change) and the position of today's date just gives an indication of how far along I am into a task I took up on Jun 1, 2012. That's all I need it for - a better visual indication of my current status. I've found a lot of jquery timeline plugins but they are too complex for what I'm trying to do. Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: plz post what you have tried or what plugins you found complex?

Comment: I've looked at jquery timelinexml & jquery timeline slider, im not saying they are too complex to understand - im saying they are too heavy weight & do so much more than I'm looking for.

Comment: Having three timestamps, it should be easy to calculate how far in percent the middle one is into the “range” the other two are spanning up – something like `(end-start)/(middle-start)*100`. And with a percentage value, simply (absolutely) positioning the middle one is easy as well – the accuracy you’ll be getting should be enough for this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably do something like this:

http://codepen.io/sheepysheep60/pen/lywCE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        // Get the end date
    end = new Date(2014, 2, 10).getTime() / 1000;
    // Start date
    start = new Date(2012, 6, 1).getTime() / 1000;
    // Today's date
    today = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

    // Percent = the string, of the rounded number, of today / end date * 100
    percent = String(Math.round((today-start)/(end-start)*100)) + "%"; // = ~ 64

    //Change the markers left css to the percent variable
    $("#marker").css('left', percent);
});
</script>
```